# Firebase Security Rule fails even though the request would be correct

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've programmed a web app with TypeScript and I have a problem with Firebase Firestore. I run the following request and it's disallowed due to a Firestore Security Rule:

```js
export async function setNewAppointment(appointment: Appointment) {
  const user = auth.currentUser;

  await addDoc(collection(db, "appointments"), {
    user_id: "blah",
    id: appointment.id,
    title: appointment.title,
    start_time: Timestamp.fromMillis(appointment.start_time),
    end_time: Timestamp.fromMillis(appointment.end_time),
    description: appointment.description,
    location: appointment.location,
  });
}
```

This is my Firebase Security Rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
            allow read, write: if false;
        }
        match /users/{userId} {
            allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
        }
        match /appointments/{appointmentId} {
            allow read, write: if "blah" == resource.data.user_id;
        }
    }
}
```

My Error message: "Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions."

Comment: Only the bottom rule doesn't work, the one above works perfectly. The user is also logged in and the request also works with deactivated Securety Rules. "blah" is just a placeholder. I wanted to use something static first so there is a higher chance of success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`resource.data`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation) is an object containing existing data in the document but as you are trying to create a new document, `resource` is null. Try using `request.resource` instead that contains the the data that'll be present if operation succeeds:

```
match /appointments/{appointmentId} {
  allow read: if <rule>;
  allow write: if "blah" == request.resource.data.user_id;
}
```

Comment: THANKS @Dharmaraj You fixed the bug. It doesn't have to be "resource.data.user_id" but "request.resource.data.user_id".

Comment: Note that this rule will not work for the read operation. You should separate it in two different rules.